# How to access individual collection data from a database with multiple collections in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building an express app that accesses at least two different databases in MongoDB. I was able to make get routes work for a single database. But I need to access another database which has multiple collections.

Here is the models file

**allModels.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { tgsConnection, dMaxConnection} = require('../connection/connections');

// create schema
const tgSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lon: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    lat: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
})


const dmaxSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    surge: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    ymd: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    lon: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    lat: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
},
    { collection : 'Dmax'}
)

// compile our model
const TideGauge = tgsConnection.model('TideGauge', tgSchema);
const Dmax = dMaxConnection.model('Dmax', dmaxSchema);

// export model
module.exports = {
    TideGauge,
    Dmax,
};
```

Under the **Dmax** model, I have imported 882 collections (imported 882 csvs using mongoimport) and I want to access these imported collections as a get request as follows:

```
    // get observed surge
    app.get('/alltgs/:id/obs_surge', async (req, res) => {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const tg = await TideGauge.find({_id : id});
        const tgName = tg[0].name;
        console.log(`tide gauge name is: ${tgName}`);
        const tgDmax = await Dmax.aguadilla,pr_263a_usa.find({});
        console.log(tgDmax);
    })
```

I tried using `Dmax.find({})` as well as `Dmax.collectionName.find({})` to access the data stored under the collection but it didn't work. Instead I am getting the following error

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
app is listening on port 4000
MongoDB :: connected allTgs
MongoDB :: connected dailyMaxSurge
MongoDB :: allTgs tidegauges.find({"_id":"60950ed93f528b6b344921cd"},{"projection":{}})
tide gauge name is: aguadilla,pr_263a_usa
(node:2280) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at C:\Users\mi292519\OneDrive\gssrDB\index.js:98:54
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2280) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2280) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How can I access the data under each collection?

Answer (score 0):

As there are several collections in the database, a separate callback function needs to be used. This can be done by first connecting to the second database and using the callback function to access the requested collection.

```
 app.get('/alltgs/:id/obs_surge', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const tg = await TideGauge.find({_id : id});
    const tgName = tg[0].name;
    console.log(`tide gauge name is: ${tgName}`);
    
    // connect to the dmax db
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dailyMaxSurge',    {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("connected to dailyMaxSurge")

        mongoose.connection.db.collection(tgName, function (err, collection) {
            collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, data){
            // console.log(data); // it will print your collection data
            const timeSeries = data;
            res.send(timeSeries);
        });
   });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('unable to connect to dailyMaxSurge')
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```